# HobbyPCB IQ32 SDR Data modes cable?

Tags: hf, digital-modes

has anyone DIY datamodes cable for HobbyPCB IQ32 SDR ?

Im thinking of using SPKR/MIC/PTT port and expose it either towards external USB soundcard (or USB soundcard stick), or directly to laptop USB.

Port is Baofeng UV-R3 TRRS wired (Sleeve-GND, 2nd ring - PTT, 1st ring - MIC, Tip - SPKR).

Thanks, 73 Vlado 9A5MPV

Comment: Hello Vlado, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!